# Outlook 2010 Auto Print Rule not printing body

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, printing, email-filter

I've set up a rule in outlook 2010 to print all emails with "order" in the subject. It then prints to my receipt printer ([Star SP-742](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/default.aspx?printerCode=SP700)).

The issue I'm having is that when the rule executes the printing, the printer only prints the header info (From, To, and subject), but not the body of the email where it shows the order.

If I manually click print, then it also prints the body section.

Please advice, Thanks!

P.S.
I'd also like to avoid printing the headers at all since it takes up lot of space on the paper since, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: In its current form, this question is off topic because it is business related. Super User is for users who have a question about personal computer hardware, computer software, or networking. We are not a tech support web site. You can [edit] your question to remove any wording related to your business and it will probably be acceptable. Otherwise, it might end up closed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting my email from Gmail via IMAP. I decided to switch to POP3 and now the "print it" rule is printing the body. It seems to be a bug in accounts that receive IMAP email.

If anyone has an actual solution please respond thanks.